# C# IronXL (Excel) + LINQ memory issue

Tags: c#, linq, memory, materialize, ironxl

My goal is to find all the cells in an Excel containing a specific text. The Excel is quite large (about 2Mb) and has about 22 sheets. Historically we had problems with `Interop`, so I found `IronXL` which I love the way it operates.

The problem is that at some point, the RAM memory increases above 2Gb, and of course it's very slow.

I'm aware of the materialization issue, so I'm trying to avoid `ToList()` or `Count()` when using LINQ.

The first "problem" I found with `IronXL` is that the `Cell` class doesn't have any field specifying the sheet name where it is contained, so I divided the code in 2 sections:

1. The LINQ to find all the cells containing the text
2. Then I iterate in all previous results to store the desired cell info + sheet name where it was found in my custom class `MyCell`

The custom class:

```
class MyCell
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public string Location;
    public string SheetName;
    public MyCell(int x, int y, string location, string sheetName)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Location = location;
        SheetName = sheetName;
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
List<MyCell> FindInExcel(WorkBook wb, string textToFind)
{
    List<MyCell> res = new List<MyCell>();

    var cells = from sheet in wb.WorkSheets
                from cell in sheet
                where cell.IsText && cell.Text.Contains(textToFind)
                select new { cell, sheet };
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        res.Add(new MyCell(cell.cell.ColumnIndex, cell.cell.RowIndex, cell.cell.Location, cell.sheet.Name));
    }

    return res;
}
```

To test my method, I call:

```
WorkBook excel = WorkBook.Load("myFile.xlsx");
var results = FindInExcel(excel, "myText");
```

What happens when I execute and debug the code is indeed very weird. The LINQ query is executed very fast, and in my case I get 2 results. Then it starts iterating in the `foreach`, and the first 2 times the values are added to the list, so, everything is perfect. But the 3rd time, when it evaluates if any other item is available, is when the memory reaches 2Gb and takes like 10 seconds.

I observed the same behaviour when I do this:

```
int count = cells.Count()
```

I'm aware this is materializing the results, but what I don't understand is why I get the 2 first results in the `foreach` so fast, and it's only in the last step where the memory increases.

Seeing this behavior, it seems clear the code knows somewhere how many items has found without having to call the `Count()`, otherwise it would be slow the first time the "foreach" is called.

Just to know if I was getting crazy, I tried to put this small code in the `FindInExcel` method:

```
int cnt = 0;
foreach (var cell in cells)
{
    res.Add(new MyCell(cell.cell.ColumnIndex, cell.cell.RowIndex, cell.cell.Location, cell.sheet.Name));
    cnt++;

    if (cnt == 2)
        break;
}
```

In this last case, I don't have the memory issue and I finally get a `List` of 2 items with the cells I want, and without any memory issue.

What am I missing? Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do without materializing the results? I even tried to move to the `.NET Framework 4.8.1` to see if some bug was fixed, but I'm getting the same behavior.

Note: If I use this code in a small Excel, it runs very fast.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you run your profiler? If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks Dai! Do you mean using some external tool? I just used the embedded debugger of Visual Studio 2019, that's how I saw this code consumes about 2Gb of RAM when I debug it. Is there a better way?

Comment: There are a couple of assumptions that you are making that are probably false.  "The LINQ query is executed very fast, and in my case I get 2 results. Then it starts iterating". The way standard Linq queries should work is that it does nothing until you start iterating/ enumerating the results. If you look at the variable in visual studio debugger, it should first show nothing but allow you to expand the results and shows a warning that if you do expand, it will enumerate your IEnumerable. As I understand it, VS debugger has a timeout so it may be that you only see two results before it stops.

Comment: Secondly "Seeing this behaviour, it seems clear the code knows somewhere how many items has found without having to call the "Count()", otherwise it would be slow the first time the "foreach" is called" This is also probably false due to the way Linq/IEnumerable works. In fact the whole point/benefit of IEnumerable is you can start getting results immediately without needing to get all the results. But to perform a count, obviously you need to go through all results.

Comment: Bottom line is, without knowing the internals of IronXL, it is impossible to answer the question, so your best option would be to ask the people who made the software. Lastly I would not consider 2mb to be a large file excel file.

Comment: Hi sgmoore! You are right, if I try to open the variable to see the results I get a timeout, I don't reach to see any result. Actually, what you say has a lot of sense, I didn't know the query did nothing until start iterating. Maybe I get the 2 results very fast because they are found at the first Excel sheet, and maybe the IronXL has a problem with some sheet that generates this behaviour. I will try to remove some sheets to see if it's a sheet in particular that generates this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also, while your code probably helps with debugging, you really don't need to query with LINQ just to `foreach` into another type - just project to the type you want: `List<MyCell> FindInExcel(WorkBook wb, string textToFind) {
    var res = (from sheet in wb.WorkSheets from cell in sheet where cell.IsText && cell.Text.Contains(textToFind) select new MyCell(cell.cell.ColumnIndex, cell.cell.RowIndex, cell.cell.Location, cell.sheet.Name)).ToList();
    return res;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I already found the issue. There was a sheet where a hidden formula was extended to the last cell (M1048576), and so it was searching the value in all of these cells. Once removed, there is no memory issue anymore.

Thank you guys!